# Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'c2d' was corrupted. with c++

Tags: c++

I'm studying for an exam and this is on my practice test. The question is "Which type of error does the following code fragment cause?"

Why is there an error?

```
struct C2D {
    double x, y;
};

class Polygon {
    int point;
    C2D arr[];
public:
    Polygon(int point_, C2D arr_[]) {
        point = point_;
        memcpy(arr, arr_, sizeof(C2D) * point);
    };
    void print() const {
        for (int i = 0; i < point; i++) {
            cout << arr[i].x << " " << arr[i].y << endl;
        }
    };
};


int main() {
    C2D c2d[3];

    c2d[0].x = 1;
    c2d[0].y = 2;

    c2d[1].x = 3;
    c2d[1].y = 4; 

    c2d[2].x = 5;
    c2d[2].y = 6;

    Polygon p1(3, c2d);
    p1.print();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't specify number of elements for the member

```
    C2D arr[];
```

so there are no memory allocated for that.

You should use `std::vector` to allocate elements dynamically.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

struct C2D {
    double x, y;
};

class Polygon {
    int point;
    std::vector<C2D> arr;
public:
    Polygon(int point_, C2D arr_[]) : arr(point_) { // allocate point_ elements for arr
        point = point_;
        memcpy(arr.data(), arr_, sizeof(C2D) * point); // copy data using data()
    };
    void print() const {
        for (int i = 0; i < point; i++) {
            cout << arr[i].x << " " << arr[i].y << endl;
        }
    };
};


int main() {
    C2D c2d[3];

    c2d[0].x = 1;
    c2d[0].y = 2;

    c2d[1].x = 3;
    c2d[1].y = 4; 

    c2d[2].x = 5;
    c2d[2].y = 6;

    Polygon p1(3, c2d);
    p1.print();
    
    return 0;
}
```